# How to synchronize Typeahead.js display from multiple sources?

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I want to show suggestions from multiple sources, some via preftech and some via remote datasets. The problem is that suggestions are displayed first with prefecth results, then with prefecth and remote datasets. Is it possible to wait all the datasets before displaying suggestions ?